# Python - Convert JSON Schema to JSON template

Tags: python, json

Have been through what seems every page/guidance on the web and wanted to ask before i go away and try to create my own...

Is there a package or simple method of converting a JSON schema in python to a basic JSON template?

i.e. removing the type, pattern, required options and leaving the core empty JSON template?

On a very basic level:
{'name':{'type':'string'}} ==> {'name':''}

Have been reading all the documents associated with the schema readers and none seem to convert back to basic except python_jsonschema_objects but that, from what i can tell struggles with multi-level and only exports the value if it has a default value, otherwise must populate all the values manually.

Thank you

Comment: I had a similar requirement a year or so ago and I ended up with writing my own script. Take a look at [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Cerberus](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/) or [Genson](https://github.com/wolverdude/genson/), maybe something changed in the meantime which could help you with this... Otherwise, I can try to dig out my snippet...

Comment: Hi errata, if your able to would be great thanks.. will also check out these three links supplied thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I was using for similar purpose long time ago, hope you will find it helpful or at least a good starting point to solve your problem!

```py
import json

# Define default values to use for each type, adjust as needed
default_values = {
    'string': '',
    'int': 0,
    'integer': 0,
    'number': 0,
    'array': [],
    'list': [],
    'tuple': [],
    'dict': {},
    'object': {},
    'boolean': 'false',
}


# Iterate the schema and return simplified dictionary or JSON string
def schema_to_json(s, to_json=False):
    res = {k: default_values[v['type']] for k, v in s.items()}
    return json.dumps(res) if to_json else res


# Pass your schema to function and get simplified version back
schema = {
    'name': {'type': 'string'},
    'age': {'type': 'integer'},
}

py_dict = schema_to_json(schema)  # Will return Python dictionary
json_string = schema_to_json(schema, True)  # Will return JSON string
```

Comment: Hi again Errata, thats great thank you, will have a play with that n see what results i get cheers

Comment: Good luck and feel free to accept the answer if you think it solved your problem ;)

Comment: Hey @Sierra4x4, if you find this helpful and if it solved your problem, feel free to mark this as accepted answer! Thanks! ;)